# How to use tensorflow SimpleRNNCell process batch dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Tensorflow to create Seq2Seq model. I try to use mini batch to process dataset. When I build dataset using `batch()` method in Tensorflow, the dataset shape becomes `(None,10)`. However, when feed data to `SimpleRNNCell` it raises error:

`ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'simple_rnn_cell/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [10], [10,10].`

The code is like this:

```
    def decoder(self, input_x, real_y, encoder_outputs, training=False):

      decoder_state, cell_states = encoder_outputs, []

      predict_shape = (5, 1)
      output = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.zeros(predict_shape), dtype=tf.float32)

      for x in range(self.max_output):
        # below code raises error, here output and decoder_state shape is  (5, 1) (?, 10)
        output, decoder_state = self.decoder_rnn(output, decoder_state)
```